# public MAMP mysql database

Tags: mysql, php

I am making a database for my family but they live in other places and I run the database so they are on another network. when I try to download data out of my database on my local network it works but when I try it on someone else his network it does not work because it keeps loading without doing anything. my port for my database in my pc and router are opened. I am not getting error messages in my PHP log file. how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Don't put a databse in the open. see if your router has openvpn and secure the connection over that. Further all incoming conection on the router have to be bridged/router to the port on the computer. But as all computers on your local networkl have access, this is a network problem and not a dba problem

Comment: how can I fix the network problem because I never did anything with networking or where can I see errors of networking?

Comment: if i set my ip behind the link i get the respond: ^  but when I don't type the port I get no response